# Working of SymmentricDS replication in Mysql DataBase

Tags: symmetricds

Am new to SymmentricDS, Is there any possible way to automatically replicate new tables to other server when created without adding them to below tables.

sym_channel

sym_trigger

sym_trigger_router

And also can anyone help me out to replicate ALTER table statement for existing tables?

Answer (score 0):

Use the same way new tables are created to add their configuration to symmetricDS tables. The engine will pick up the new configuration, add dB triggers on newly added tables, routing and other rules and start synchronizing their content without having to restart the engine

How to sync DDL statements could be learned here: https://www.symmetricds.org/docs/how-to/sync-schema-ddl-changes (symmadmin command)